# Swift -How to get the center frame of a button's titleLabel and not the button itself

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a custom segmented control with 4 segments with a button in each segment. I had to make a change to the button's contentEdgeInsets:

```
// eg of the second button
customSegmentedControl.secondButton?.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -35, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

The slider originally slid to each segment using `button.frame.midX`. After changing the `contentEdgeInsets` when the slider slides to a segment it looks as if it's in the wrong position because the title is no longer in the center of the button.  I tried to change the slider to slide to the center of the button's button.titleLabel: `button.titleLabel!.frame.midX` but a weird bug occurs where the slider slides incorrectly.

```
for button in buttons {
            
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

        self.slider.frame.origin.x = button.titleLabel!.frame.midX // button.frame.midX was what was originally used
         // if it's the selected button break ...
    })
}
```

How can I get the slider to slide to the center of the button's `titleLabel`? For example I want it to slide to the middle of the word Pencil which is the title of the button with its `contentEdgeInsets` changed and not the middle of the button itself.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of coordinate systems. You have no idea what coordinate system `button.titleLabel!.frame` is in, so you've got this CGRect but it is of no use to you.

But you do know what coordinate system the *slider's* `frame` needs to be in; it is in terms of its superview.

So *convert* `button.titleLabel!.frame` to the coordinate system of the slider's superview, and now you can move the slider meaningfully.

```
let convertedRect = slider.superview!.convert(button.titleLabel!.frame, from: button.titleLabel!)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just got on an important phone call, once I finish I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: yeah I've heard that one before :)

Comment: Cannot invoke 'convert' with an argument list of type '(from: UILabel)'

Comment: Fixed, I was typing off top of head

Comment: still crooked: **let convertedRect = slider.superview!.convert(button.titleLabel!.frame, from: button.titleLabel!); self.slider.frame.origin.x = convertedRect.midX**

Comment: Well you do not want the slider's `origin.x` to be at the middle of the button?

Comment: oh yeah, that makes sense, gimme a sec, let me position the middle of the slider instead of its origin.x